# How do I set up subdomains?

Tags: networking, website, domain

Basically, I have a server domain (example.com) which points to a web server.

The question is, I want another link (fileshare.example.com) pointing to a server at my house that is going to run H5AI. How would I achieve this? I'm using Dreamhost.

Comment: You're probably looking for the term "subdomain", and there's nothing special about it – as far as DNS is concerned, "ideaman924.com" and "fileshare.ideaman924.com" are two completely separate entries, which merely are under the same zone in terms of ownership, but each contains its own data (that is, they can point to different servers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the Dreamhost interface is like, but you should be able to add an `A Record`, where you can specify a subdomain and the IP address you wish for it to point to, somewhere within the DNS settings.